xfreerdp audio issues
I am trying to enable xfreerdp on Ubuntu 24.04, which I need for work. Everything works fine, except for audio. When I try to run things like Youtube on the remote machine, audio works fine, but when I try to use a microphone (eg for a Teams call), the audio starts stuttering horribly, there are 5 second long skips, and the whole remote machine freezes sometimes.
The remote machines are owned and operated by my companys IT department, so I can't change any settings on them. When used in Ubuntu itself, the microphone and sound work perfectly fine.
FreeRDP version is 2.11.5 (tried with FreeRdp3, didn't work either)
The command I use for running xfreerdp is:
xfreerdp connection.rdp /scale:140 /network:auto /sound:sys:alsa /microphone:sys:alsa
I've tried a lot of different parameters for the /sound and /microphone options:

format:1, format:0
latency:everything between 200 and 8000
running with only /sound and /microphone without any additional parameters
running with and without /network:auto
running with different quality settings

Whenever the audio drops happen, I see a message in the terminal:
alsa lib pcm.c 8740 underrun occurred
I've tried following some advice online for setting the audio parameters, but my Ubuntu installation doesn't have pulseaudio, instead systemctl status | grep pulse shows only pipewire-pulse.service running.
I'm pretty new to Linux and don't understand how audio works yet, so if anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

If you're having trouble with audio stuttering and freezing while using xfreerdp on Ubuntu 24.04, it might be due to issues with ALSA or how FreeRDP interacts with your system's audio setup. Since you're using PipeWire, try switching the audio backend to PipeWire in your xfreerdp command by using /sound:sys:pipewire and /microphone:sys:pipewire instead of ALSA. Additionally, you might want to check if there's a network latency or bandwidth issue contributing to the stuttering. If the problem persists, consider using ThinLinc as an alternative remote desktop solution. It often provides better performance and stability for remote sessions, especially in environments where audio and multiple sessions are crucial.
